# How to get the vector in the same direction in local coordinate system as the global?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, coordinate-systems, rotations

I have a robot simulation model which is in terms of local coordinate system $x, y, z$. so every joint here will be with respect to a parent.

I have some data about an action and these actions are given in terms of the global coordinate system.

Now since I am feeding this data into the model and the axis are rotated, but the direction in space of the vector would remain the same.

So now I want to find the coordinates of this vector (which was pointing in some direction in the global frame) in terms of the local frame

Here is a [desmos visualization](https://www.desmos.com/3d/1bcecc2f72). The RGB longer vectors are the global $x, y, z$. The shorter RGB are the local $x_l, y_l , z_l$ The grey vector is the vector $v$ which I am interested in, here $v$ is defined in terms of the global axis. Keeping the pointing direction same I want the vector in terms of local $x_l, y_l , z_l$.

How did I get the local axis?

- I had a quaternion which was used to rotate the 3 basis axis

Comment: Rotate your original vector in the opposite direction, i.e. the inverse rotation. That's how it will look in the new coordinate system.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thanks for the reply. I already know, how the vector should look in the new coordinate system. I want to find the coordinates or the direction of this vector in the new system. If I just take the inverse rotation then the vector will again come back in terms of the global coordinate system. And thus won't provide me with the coordinates in terms of the local system